# Javascript prompt variable returning NaN

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to take two variables add them within a function and return a new variable in the form of an alert. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for any help!

```
var num1 = prompt("How much money do you have?");
var num2 = prompt("How much money will you add?");
var a = parseInt(num1);
var b = parseInt(num2);
var result = 0;

function addTwoNumbers(a,b) {
    result = a + b;
}

addTwoNumbers();
return result;
alert("you will have " + result);
```

Comment: I recommend to read a tutorial about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html

Comment: You should learn how to "debug". For instance, you can put a "breakpoint" on the `result = a + b;` line, and view the values of `a` and `b` right in the debugger pane. You would see that they were undefined, because you didn't pass them in, and that would have led you directly to the root of your problem. If you don't know how to debug or use tools like Chrome devtools, stop everything you're doing and learn now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not passing any parameters to the function. `a` and `b` have been declared, but aren't being passed to the function.

```
var num1 = prompt("How much money do you have?");
var num2 = prompt("How much money will you add?");
var a = parseInt(num1);
var b = parseInt(num2);

function addTwoNumbers(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}
alert("you will have " + addTwoNumbers(a, b));
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/bt3x829p/1/

**Edit 1**

To explain to what I mean.

```
function addTwoNumbers(apple, banana) {
    return apple + banana;
}
```

The parameter I specified above are placeholders for the actual arguments which will be passed. In the function you'd refer to the passed arguments through the parameters you specified.

Comment: While you are at it you should also `return` the result instead.

Comment: Well, I would have removed the `result` assignment :P

Comment: And then you either  have to assign the return value to `result` or put the call inside `alert`.

Comment: Thanks for the response so my understanding is I will always have to specify arguments even if they are already in the function? Also I'm new could you let me know why my question has received a down vote?

Comment: @SethPatch your question probably received a down vote because it is a very simple question, and if you looked at tutorials or googled "javascript functions" or something like that you would have known where you went wrong. Yes you always have to specify arguments, when you defined the function parameters you were simply telling the function that it will take two arguments, you never actually passed anything to it.

Comment: @SethPatch check **Edit 1**.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feed back I'm trying to learn via Lynda, I'll try to do a little more research before I post!

Comment: @SethPatch generally you'll receive good feedback from people if you've showed that you've tried yourself at fixing an issue, so outlining everything you've tried and all the research you've done.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `a` and `b` as parameters of your function, but you're not actually passing in the values. Either get rid of the formal parameters from the function declaration, or pass the values when you call it.